# Social sharing for web platform is not working in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

**explanation -**

I am trying to use social sharing in my ionic Application using https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing/ , for ios and Android 
it is working 
**But when I try to use share on facebook , twitter , linkdin for web platform Api is not available**  How can I do it for web platform

Comment: Please add the code that you got so far so that we know what you did and want to do. Then also describe what exactly your question is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can share links to social sites using these api's

```
 shareTwitter(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  var twitterWindow = window.open('https://twitter.com/share?url=' + document.URL, 'twitter-popup', 'height=350,width=600');
  if(twitterWindow.focus) { twitterWindow.focus(); }
    return false;
 }
 shareFacebook(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var facebookWindow = window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + document.URL, 'facebook-popup', 'height=350,width=600');
  if(facebookWindow.focus) { facebookWindow.focus(); }
    return false;
 }
 shareGooglePlus(e) {
  //  var _this = this;
  e.preventDefault();
  var GooglePlusWindow = window.open('https://plus.google.com/share?url=' + document.URL, 'googleplus-popup', 'height=350,width=600');
  if(GooglePlusWindow.focus) { GooglePlusWindow.focus(); }
    return false;
 }
 shareLinkedIn(e) {
  var url =  document.URL
  var title = this.contributionDetails.Title;
  var text = document.URL;
  window.open('http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url='+url+'&title='+title, 'sharer', 'left=0,top=0,width=650,height=420,personalbar=0,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0');
 }
```

**HTML File**

```
        <ul>
          <li><a (click)="shareFacebook($event)" class="fbicon"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a></li>
          <li><a (click)="shareTwitter($event)" class="twittericon"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a></li>
          <li><a  (click)="shareGooglePlus($event)" class="gpicon"><span class="fa fa-google-plus"></span></a></li>
          <li><a  (click)="shareLinkedIn($event)" class="linkicon"><span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span></a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: Actually it is not working , if window.open() is supported by IONIC OR TypeScript ?

Comment: thanks bhaiya , Actually I am facing problem , can you add the html part if possible

Comment: HTML ->>>>>>> <span class="facebook-share" (click)='shareFacebook()'  data-js="facebook-share">Share on Facebook</span>
>>>>>>>>>>     TS   ->  shareFacebook(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var facebookWindow = window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + document.URL, 'facebook-popup', 'height=350,width=600');
  if(facebookWindow.focus) { facebookWindow.focus(); }
    return false;
 }

Comment: @AnuragRanjan look at my html file

Comment: thanks bhai .. I looked you are from pakistan ... so no bhaiya , it's bhai . thanks alot

Comment: @AnuragRanjan i have posted it in answer above

Comment: thanks, it works for me. Is there any way to share image in facebook and see the preview?

Comment: Is there any way to share text? @AnuragRanjan

Answer (score -1):

As per the cordova-plugin github repository, It supports only Mobile Platforms (Android, IOS, Windows). It doesn't support desktop version. You need to add support from your end.

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin/tree/master/src

Comment: the plugins says it supports browser too.

Comment: For browser, you need to use web share API as per the https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin#5-web-share-api. It only supports Chrome.